# Extracting users from AD group and adding to BookInPolicy

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to extract emails of users in one or more (non-mail enabled) AD-groups and pass that output into Set-CalendarProcessing. I can't figure out how to get the list in the right format for the command to accept it.

I'll let the code do the talking:

```
$allbookers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "sec AXD" | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Mail
$ab_list = '"{0}"' -f (($allbookers | select -ExpandProperty Mail) -join '","')
```

The output from $ab_list is exactly how I want it: "name1@company.com","name2@company.com" etc

If I then do this...

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity $resourcename -BookInPolicy $ab_list
```

... I get a warning in output: 
WARNING: Couldn't find object ""name1@company.com","name2@company.com""
  (and also the Bookinpolicy is then empty).

But if I copy/paste the output from $ab_list and manually insert it into the above command it works.

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity $resourcename -BookInPolicy "name1@company.com","name2@company.com"
```

So what am I doing wrong? Clearly it's something about the format of the output, but how do I "convert" it?

Comment: I would say that the below answer is most likely correct, but try to remove the quotation marks and send the values as `-Bookinpolicy a@b.com,c@d.com,e@f.com` This is the other suggested way to pass the values into the flag

Comment: Also, if you run get-mailbox on one of these users with no mailbox, does it error or do you still get anything back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess here that when you specify `"foo","bar"` as the parameter, it isn't provided as a single string to the cmdlet – before that happens, it is parsed *by PowerShell itself* into an array containing two values, and the cmdlet receives an array variable. So that's what the -BookInPolicy option expects as well – it needs an array of addresses such as what you have in `$allbookers | select -expand mail`. It isn't actually able to parse your pre-formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. This is how I looks right now. The next thing to do is to pass group names from the command line so I can avoid having to edit the script all the time. I'm sure there are tons of optimizations I can do to the code, but at least it's now functional enough for me to use. :)

Thank you for everyone and their helpful comments! \o/

```
$axd = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "sec AXD" | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Mail

# Joining all the groups to one big happy family, remember to add additional groups below
$allbookers = $axd

# Creating array with booker e-mail addresses
$newBookers = $allbookers | select -ExpandProperty Mail

if ($AddBookers = 1)
{
    $previousBookers = (Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity $resourcename).BookInPolicy

    # Make sure temp variable is empty
    $temp = $null

    # Copy new bookers to every booker list
    $EveryBooker = $newBookers

    # Looping through all previously added bookers and extracting e-mail address from each user and adding to every booker list
    foreach ($prevBooker in $previousBookers)
    {
        $temp = Get-Mailbox -Identity $prevBooker | Select-String PrimarySMTPAddress
        $EveryBooker += $temp       
    }

    # Sort list and remove duplicates
    $EveryBooker = $EveryBooker | sort -Unique

    # Set the Bookinpolicy with the updated list
    Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity $resourcename -BookInPolicy $EveryBooker
}
elseif ($AddBookers = 0)
{
    Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity $resourcename -BookInPolicy $newBookers
}
```